# I want SQL query to relate two tables data ,where both tables have only one column each

Tags: sql

I have two tables Country and City. Both tables have only one column.
In country table I have values as 
INDIA,UK,US and so on.
IN City table I have values like
LONDON,BANGALORE,DELHI,WASHINGTON and so on.

I want to write SQL query such that output should be like when I select UK ,LONDON should come in front of that ,when US ,WASHINGTON Should appear in US row and so on.

Please provide me the query.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a foreign key in the City table, then you join the tables together

```
ALTER TABLE city ADD COLUMN country VARCHAR(25);
ALTER TABLE city ADD PRIMARY KEY (city);
ALTER TABLE country ADD PRIMARY KEY (country);
ALTER TABLE city ADD FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES country(country)
SELECT CONCAT(city, ", ", country) FROM city JOIN country USING (country)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to make relation between these two tables since they have ONLY ONE column. You have to add [Country] column to the [City] table to known what country a city belongs to.

Comment: Better yet, create a PK column an have THAT column in the City table as a FK

Answer (score 0):

you need a third table to store the relationships between the two tables and you need to add ID fields to each of your existing tables.

```
table city
id | city
1 | chicago

table country
id | country
3 | United States

table lookup
id | city_id | country_id
5 | 1 | 3
```

you would have to perfom a JOIN to connect the tables

`SELECT * FROM`lookup`JOIN city ON lookup.city_id = city.id JOIN country ON lookup.country_id = country.id`

hope this helps

Comment: Hi as asked by interviewer We can consider  country as unique but we should not take  more columns.If we take Country as UK we should get cities related to UK that are stored in City table.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options here.

The first thing to consider is whether you want to use the city/country **name** as the way of uniquely identifying a row.  Although these are very unlikely to change, its not without precidence.  `Bombay => Mumbai`, `Ceylon => Sri Lnka`, spelling mistakes, etc.  Personally I'd recommend having an integer field as the PRIMARY KEY / UNIQUE IDENTIFIER on each table.  You can then change the names (including spelling mistakes) without impacting anything else in the database.

You then need to relate the two tables.  One option is to add a field to the CITY table that points to a unique identifier in the COUNTRY table.  An alternative is to have a completely seperate table of two columns, relating each City's unique identifier to it's associated Country's unique identifier.